# Eclipse Oomph: Suppress Welcome Page

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I want to create an Eclipse installer which installs an Eclipse that doesn't show a welcome page.

[This blog post](https://kthoms.wordpress.com/2020/03/19/eclipse-oomph-suppress-welcome-page/) suggests to create a settings file with a ResourceCreationTask:

```xml
<setupTask
      xsi:type="setup:ResourceCreationTask"
      id="rtt.suppress.welcome.page"
      content="eclipse.preferences.version=1\nshowIntro=false"
      targetURL="${workspace.location|uri}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.prefs"
      encoding="UTF-8">
  <description>Suppress showing of the Welcome page.</description>
</setupTask>
```

The author then adds a comment that this leads to a problem because `${workspace.location}` is undefined during installation. The suggested solution however is to replace `${workspace.location}` with `${install.location}/ws`. That would create a file in a subdirectory of the install location and doesn't help unless this location happens to be the workspace.

Another suggestion is to `targetURL="${osgi.instance.area|file}.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.prefs"`. That doesn't help either.

Unfortunately I was unable to find a documentation on which variables can be used with Oomph.